# restassured - parsing response and searching by value

Tags: rest-assured

I have following REST API response:

```
"items": 
[   
        {   
          "empid": "1234",  
          "name": "Santosh",  
          "hiredby": "Mark",  
          "date": "2017-01-31,00:19:41 PST",  
     },  
        {  
          "empid": "5678",  
          "name": "Kumar",  
          "hiredby": "Bob",  
          "date": "2017-01-31,08:30:31 PST"  
          }  
    ]
```

My query is : - How do i get empid based on querying name as Kumar.

For example: I need to find "Kumar" name and get his empid. (that is, search by name and get his empid as response) I'm able to get the response and store it in Response object. but, from response object how can i traverse and query to get the required value.

Also,
I tried by retrieving as:

```
String name = get(REST_ENDPOINT).then().body("items.name",hasItems("Kumar")).extract().path("items.empid").toString();
```

when i print the response i get collection of the empid like [1234,5678], where as my expectation is to get only 5678.

Do I need to parse via JSONArray and JSONObject and iterate the response?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
response1.jsonPath().getList("collect { it.credentials.findAll { it.credentialType == 'Ban User Name'}.credentialId }.flatten()")
```